# Comparing multiple bernoulli distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bernoulli-distribution, polling

Suppose that we have 3 groups of people (CS/Stats/History students) and we question student in each group if they like chocolate. So for each group we have the percentage of students that like chocolate.

My null hypothesis is: There shouldn't be any difference between the groups. In other words, the percentage should be more or less the same.

My question is, how do I measure this? Which statistical test would tell if one group deviates from the others? (If not possible, I'm willing to compare them in pairs)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, ok a few things.

The first question about "is there any difference between groups" can be handled with an ANOVA.  People might be quick to disagree since the outcome of the study is binomial and not continuous.  This would be problematic if one group really did or did not like chocolate.  In that case, you could fit a logistic regression and do a likelihood ratio test between a model which adjusts for group and a model with an intercept only.  That is really similar to ANOVA and has the added benefit of having the right likelihood.  For large samples, it shouldn't matter.

If you reject the null of no association from the ANOVA, you can apply Tukey HSD to perform pairwise tests and control for the false positive rate appropriately.